# VM Exception on variable assignment

Tags: gas, exceptions, proxy-contracts

I'm encountering a problem related to the gas (I guess).

Please note that I'm using the proxy pattern for upgradeable smart contracts: [CODE EXAMPLE HERE](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-sdk/tree/master/packages/lib/contracts/upgradeability) - [Explanation from Openzeppelin](https://blog.openzeppelin.com/proxy-patterns/)

I'm trying to call the function `initialize` defined in a **logic contract**:

```
/* NOT WORKING EXAMPLE */
function initialize(address superAddress) public {
    require(!_initialized, 'Contract already initialized');
    _ownerAddress = superAddress;
    _ceoAddress = superAddress;
    _cfoAddress = superAddress;
    _cooAddress = superAddress;

    _initialized = true;
}
```

When I'm calling `initialize` I'm getting the error:
    **Error: "Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert"**

And this is the related log:

```
 [08:53:32] eth_sendTransaction
 [08:53:32]   Transaction: 0x7a46396621502cb541f0509ff975fb9695b15d4efd9a5d7c27b320755066a37f
 [08:53:32]   Gas usage: 88988
 [08:53:32]   Block Number: 245
 [08:53:32]   Block Time: Tue Oct 01 2019 08:53:32 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time)
 [08:53:32]   Runtime Error: revert
 [08:53:32] eth_getBlockByNumber
```

But, when I'm commenting a couple of assignments in the initialize function (like below) **everything is working**:

```
/* WORKING EXAMPLE */
function initialize(address superAddress) public {
    require(!_initialized, 'Contract already initialized');
    _ownerAddress = superAddress;
    _ceoAddress = superAddress;
    /* _cfoAddress = superAddress; */
    /* _cooAddress = superAddress; */

    _initialized = true;
}
```

Below an example of the call of `initialize` function on the client side:

```
contractInst.methods.initialize('0x4F9aA950b153a3D27a4f6ed738f6Ce7D4dc8cA7e').send({})
    .then(resp => console.log(resp))
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Do you have any clue of the causes of that error? And how to solve it?

Extra notes:
I'm using GANACHE and the smart contracts are developed with solidity ^0.5.0;

THANKS!

Comment: Please share your off-chain code (where you call `initialize`). The problem is more likely the result of calling this function more than once for the same contract instance.

Comment: Thank you @goodvibration . Regarding the working example, if I call more than once the `initialize` function I receive the specific error: `Error: "Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Contract already initialized"` because in the require I specified the error message. Soon I'm going to post how I call the `initalize` function.

Comment: You should by the least specify `from` and `gas` in the `{}` parameter that you pass to `send`.

Comment: It was simply the gas parameter missing! I thought I tried everything :(( Thanks a lot!